# Wordpress, replace standard word /search

Tags: wordpress, search, replace, seo

is it possible to replace the word search?

For example:

```
http://domain.com/search/helloWordl
```

to

```
http://domain.com/test/helloWordl
```

Comment: Is it the URL of the Wordpress search page ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you just need to create a new page template and save as searchpage.php, add the correct code.

Change the form action to redirect to the page you just to create and that's it.

[Read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) to better understanding, you will find the correct loop and all the steps to do that.